# How to convert mixmatch date to one uniform date in ssis?

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, ssis, etl

I have trade_date column which looks like this :

```
Trade_date
10-02-2012
1-23-2014
feb-14-2016
1/2/2012
01/02/2012
01/01/12
2014/10/26
```

I want to have one unified format after transformation which is MM/dd/yyyy.
Does anyone have this problem before or anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Assuming the data is a string/character and not a date data type?  You could write a function (or C# script task) to take in the date and do different things based off the date format you already have

Comment: I think a problem you might run into - with a date column saved as string data type - is if European dates are saved. For instance: 10-02-2012 - is that October 2nd or February 10? If you can be 100% sure no European dates are in your data, then I'd follow something with what Brad describes above, you'll have to do a script (or tsql function, or stored procedure) to convert by pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Script Component to do that, since you are looking to convert multiple date formats. First, you have to create an array of strings that contains all formats needed then you should use `DateTime.ParseExact()` function

After adding a Script Component, Make sure you add a New Output Column of type string (Or date if you are looking to convert values into date column), then use the following lines of code within the script:

```cs
string[] formats = {"dd-MM-yyyy","yyyy-MM-dd","d-M-yyyy","MMM-dd-yyyy","dd/MM/yy","yyyy/MM/dd","dd/MM/yyyy","};
Row.outColumn = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.inColumn,formats,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```